# Changing Background Color of Row using Google Sheets API v4

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to change the background color of the first row (header) in my Google spreadsheet. Based on several hours of research and reading I came up with the following code:

```
Request updateBackgroundColorRequest = new Request();
UpdateCellsRequest updateCellsRequest = new UpdateCellsRequest();

CellFormat cellFormat = new CellFormat();
Color color = new Color();
color.setRed((float) 246);
color.setGreen((float) 178);
color.setBlue((float) 107);

cellFormat.setBackgroundColor(color);

GridRange gridRange = new GridRange();
gridRange.setStartRowIndex(0);
gridRange.setEndRowIndex(1);
gridRange.setStartColumnIndex(0);
gridRange.setEndColumnIndex(14);
updateCellsRequest.setRange(gridRange);

String field = "userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor";
updateCellsRequest.setFields(field);
updateBackgroundColorRequest.setUpdateCells(updateCellsRequest);

requestList.add(updateBackgroundColorRequest);
batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.setRequests(requestList);

Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate batchUpdate = service.spreadsheets()
    .batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest);
batchUpdate.execute();
```

However, although I am able to execute this code successfully (no errors are returned by API) the background color does not change at all (I'm expecting it to change to orange but it remains white).

Did I miss something?

Comment: I think you need to check the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#color) in the documentation. "*for example, the fields of this representation can be trivially provided to the constructor of "java.awt.Color" in Java; it can also be trivially provided to UIColor's "+colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha" method in iOS; and, with just a little work, it can be easily formatted into a CSS "rgba()" string in JavaScript, as well.*"

Comment: I tried updating the colour through the API explorer and it was working fine, but copying the same request, I couldn't get it to work. It ended up being the colors needed to be updated using their own request rather than being one of many bulk requests.

Answer (score 2):

Stucked with the same problem. Thx for your code! It helps me a lot!

So the problem is in line.

```
updateBackgroundColorRequest.setUpdateCells(updateCellsRequest);
```

You need **RepeatCellRequest** class instead of **UpdateCellRequest**.

Simple request set will be like

```
requestList.add(new Request().setRepeatCell(
   new RepeatCellRequest().
   setCell(cellData).
   setRange(gridRange).
   setFields("*")));
```

All my code looks like this:

```
List<Request> requestList = new ArrayList<>();

CellFormat cellFormat = new CellFormat(); //setting cell color
Color color = new Color();
color.setRed(246f);
color.setGreen(178f);
color.setBlue(107f);

cellFormat.setBackgroundColor(color);

CellData cellData = new CellData();
cellData.setUserEnteredFormat(cellFormat);

GridRange gridRange = new GridRange(); //setting grid that we will paint
gridRange.setSheetId(1115615634); //you can find it in your URL - param "gid"
gridRange.setStartRowIndex(0);
gridRange.setEndRowIndex(1);
gridRange.setStartColumnIndex(0);
gridRange.setEndColumnIndex(14);

requestList.add(new Request().setRepeatCell(new RepeatCellRequest().setCell(cellData).setRange(gridRange).setFields("userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor")));

BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.setRequests(requestList);

final Sheets.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate batchUpdate = sheetsService.
        spreadsheets().batchUpdate("yourSpreadSheetId - find it in URL", batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest);

batchUpdate.execute();
```